# Installing Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V VM

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running on Windows 10 Pro version on a Surface Laptop, and I have enabled Hyper-V.
I created a VM to install Ubuntu 20.04 from a downloaded .iso file.
During the installation, I got prompted to erase disk and install Ubuntu as per the attached snapshot.
Will that affect my Windows partitions or it's just inside the Hyper-V ? [Erase disk prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb9CV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you setup a VM you've created a virtual disk. This prompt informed you that it will erase your virtual disk.

Comment: No, I didn't. I started immediately the Quick create, I selected the ISO file and started installation.

Comment: Okay. When you run Hyper-V Manager do you see your created virtual machine? If yes on the right pane you should have Settings your virtual machine and there you can check if you created virtual hard disk, but I think that this disk has been created and this prompt concerns to erase that disk.

Comment: Quick create option will create VHDX anyway. https://medium.com/@pzelenovic/how-to-quick-create-a-linux-ubuntu-18-04-5b7198e90249
There is no need to worry, VHDX is a separate RAW virtual disk. Ubuntu won't see any data from the Hypervisor.